# Control Server Permission and LOGON trigger

Tags: sql

I made a trigger that will check to see if the IP address of the user who is logging in matches an IP in the Allowed_IPs table. If there is a match, then the user can login. If there is not a match, then the user cannot log in.

```
ALTER TRIGGER [Logon_Screen]
    ON ALL SERVER
    FOR LOGON
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @IP VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @Matching_IP INT

SELECT @IP = EVENTDATA().value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/ClientHost)[1]','nvarchar(128)')

SET @Matching_IP = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM DAT.dbo.[Allowed_IPs] WHERE [Allowed_IP] = @IP)
        IF @Matching_IP = 0
            BEGIN
                ROLLBACK


    END
```

END

The code above works fine, but there is a strange issue. Unless the user that is logging is either a member of sysadmin or has the Control Server permission, the trigger will prevent the login from occurring even if the user's IP address is in the Allowed_IPs table. Obviously, I cannot just give all users admin privileges so what else can I do?

Comment: Making a login trigger that takes dependency on anything but `master`, `model` or `tempdb` is a recipe for disaster. When your `DAT` database goes offline, or is being restored, or whatever, all your logins are rejected. High Unavailability...

Comment: DAT just holds a couple procedures for backing up other database, it will likely never be set offline, but I see your point, can I move the Allowed_IP table to the master database?

Comment: `never set` as in `I can somehow magically guarantee uptime`...

Comment: Still however, do you have any idea why you must have admin permission to pass my login trigger above? Any answers will be very helpful, thank you in advance.